# Limit of this series: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum^n_{k=0} \frac{k+1}{3^k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given a series, how does one calculate that limit below? I noticed the numerator is an arithmetic progression and the denominator is a geometric progression — if that's of any relevance —, but I still don't know how to solve it.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum^n_{k=0} \frac{k+1}{3^k}$$

I did it "by hand" and the result should be $\frac{9}{4}.$

Comment: ... did you mean numerator?

Comment: Pretty nearly a duplicate of question 50919, which has 5 answers already, so have a look there.

Comment: A related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-to-find-the-sum-of-this-infinite-series I also add question mentioned by @Gerry Myerson, so that they are linked to each other: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50919/

Comment: This is at the moment the only question tagged series http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series Perhaps infinite-series would be better http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-series or maybe this tag could be omited completely.

Comment: @Martin, good idea. I've deleted the "series" tag. I didn't add "infinite-series" since the question already has the "sequences-and-series" tag, which I think will suffice.

Comment: See also: [Sum of the series: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1+n}{3^n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/14554)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $X$ be a geometric random variable with probability of success $p=2/3$, so that
$$
{\rm P}(X=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p = \frac{2}{{3^k }}, \;\; k=1,2,3,\ldots.
$$
From the easy-to-remember fact that ${\rm E}(X)=1/p$, it follows that
$$
\frac{3}{2} + 1 = {\rm E}(X) + 1 = {\rm E}(X + 1) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {(k + 1){\rm P}(X = k) = 2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{k + 1}}{{3^k }}} } .
$$
Hence
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{k + 1}}{{3^k }}} = \frac{5}{4}.
$$

Comment: This approach is of general interest, and can be used for confirmation.

Comment: +1 For giving a nice solution to a slightly boring problem! ;)

Comment: @AD. Thanks. To make the solution more interesting, here is a probabilistic derivation of the formula ${\rm E}(X)=1/p$: $X=1$ with probability $p$, and $X = 1 + \tilde X$ with probability $1-p$, where $\tilde X$ is an independent copy of $X$. Hence, ${\rm E}(X) = p\cdot 1 + (1-p)(1 + {\rm E}(X))$. Solving for ${\rm E}(X)$ gives ${\rm E}(X) = 1/p$.

Answer (score 4):

if you take the derivative of
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k
$$
you get
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}
$$
evaluating at $x=1/3$ gives
$$
\frac{1}{(1-1/3)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{3^{k-1}}
$$
subtract off the $k=1$ term to get your series
$$
9/4-1=5/4
$$
so if you want the anwer to be $9/4$, you might want to change your $1$ to a $0$ in the indexing

Answer (score 3):

For summing $\sum\frac{k}{3^k}$ use the following formula: $$(1-x)^{-2} = 1 + 2x + 3x^{2} + 4x^{3} + \cdots \qquad \Bigl[\because \small (1-x)^{-n} = 1+nx +\frac{n\cdot (n-1)}{2!}\cdot x^{2} + \cdots \Bigr]$$ Multiplying the above equation by $x$ and then putting $x=\frac{1}{3}$ we have $$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{9}+\frac{3}{27} + \frac{4}{3^{4}} + \cdots  = \frac{1}{3}\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{3}\Bigr)^{-2} = \frac{3}{4} \qquad\quad \cdots (1)$$

Also you know that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^k}= \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{3}} =\frac{1}{2} \qquad\qquad \cdots (2)$$

Add equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get your answer.

Comment: what does $+\cdots\infty$ mean?

Comment: @wildildildlife: Well it just means that there are infinite number of terms in the given series.

Comment: Perhaps, I should remove that

Answer (score 2):

By the way, the answer you got by hand is off a bit. Hopefully my hint will help you derive the correct answer.

First, note that *by definition*,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\;\sum_{k=1}^na_k$$
so I will use the infinite sum as a shorthand.

We know that
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{x^{k+1}}=(x^{-1})^2+(x^{-1})^3+\cdots=\frac{{x}^{-2}}{1-x^{-1}}=\frac{1}{x^2-x}.$$
What does that mean
$$g(x)=-x^2f'(x)$$
is? Assume (or, better, prove) that differentiation can split up over an infinite sum. Can you use this to help your computations?

Answer (score 2):

divide that formular like this.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left (\frac{k}{3^k}+\frac{1}{3^k}\right )$$

then $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{3^k}+\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{3^k}+\frac{1}{2}$$
power series
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{3^k}$$

let $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{3^k}=S$$
Then,

$$ S=1\times \frac{1}{3}+2\times \frac{1}{3^2}+3\times \frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots \cdots $$
$$\frac{1}{3}S=1\times \frac{1}{3^2}+2\times \frac{1}{3^3}+3\times \frac{1}{3^4}+\cdots \cdots $$
$$S-\frac{1}{3}S=1\times \frac{1}{3}+(2-1)\times \frac{1}{3}+(3-2)\times \frac{1}{3}\cdots \cdots =\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Answer is
$$\therefore \frac{2}{3}S=\frac{1}{2},S=\frac{3}{4}$$

$$\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are given a "constant series" $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ of this kind (maybe even with factors $k!$ in the denominator) it is often helpful to introduce a factor $x^k$ into the general term. We then are speaking of a function
$f(x):= \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k$ and want to know the value $f(1)$. Note that now we have new tools at our disposal, namely differentiation or integration with respect to $x$, multiplication by $x$ or ${1\over x}$, replacing $x^2$ by $u$, etc. By means of such operations it is then often possible to transform the power series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x^k$ into a series that we recognize as the series of a familiar function like ${1\over 1-x}$, $\cosh x$, etc.

In the example at hand we can subsume the factors ${1\over 3^k}$ into the $x^k$ and compute the value $f\bigl({1\over3}\bigr)$ at the end. This means we are now considering the function
$$f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1) x^k\ .$$
Looking at this formula we see that $f(x)=g'(x)$ for the function
$$g(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty  x^{k+1}=x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots = {x^2\over 1 -x}\ ,$$
and this is valid for all $x$ of absolute value $<1$. It follows that
$$f(x)=g'(x)={2x -x^2\over (1-x)^2}\ ;$$
therefore the value we want is $f\bigl({1\over3}\bigr)={5\over4}$.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a variant presentation of a standard solution. For now we omit convergence considerations. We include the term that has $x$ raised to the $0$-th power, because it *wants* to be included.  Let 
$$F(x)=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+ \cdots +nx^{n-1}+\cdots.$$
*Multiply* $F(x)$ by $(1-x)$. So
$$(1-x)F(x)=(1-x)(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+ \cdots +nx^{n-1}+\cdots).$$
Multiplying out the right-hand side takes some concentration.  I think it is called *long multiplication*.

But we quickly notice that the product is $1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^n+\cdots$, and conclude that
$$(1-x)F(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}.$$

**The finite sum case**: Let
$$F_n(x)=1+2x+3x^2+ \cdots +nx^{n-1}.$$
Multiply both sides by $1-x$.  We obtain
$$(1-x)F_n(x)= (1-x)(1+2x+3x^2+ \cdots +nx^{n-1})=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}-nx^n.$$
Thus, if $x \ne 1$, then
$$(1-x)F_n(x)=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}-nx^n.$$

If we wish, when $|x|\lt 1$, we can now compute 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what you have is a limit of a *finite sum*, and the limit is a series:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{3^k}:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k+1}{3^k}$$
Now, to the question you asked: there are a few tricks you can use:
1) You know that $\sum_{k=1}^nx^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}-1$ (geometric progression).
2) That implies, by deriving both sides, that $\sum_{k=1}^nkx^{k-1}=\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}(1-x)+(1-x^{n+1})}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n}+1}{(1-x)^2}$
3) From here you get that $\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}-1+x\frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^{n}+1}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{(n+1)x^{n+2}-(n+2)x^{n+1}-x^2+2x}{(1-x)^2}$.
4) Now plug in $x=\frac{1}{3}$. As $n\to\infty$, you have $x^n\to 0$. This implies that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{3^k}=\frac{-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2+2\cdot\frac{1}{3}}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2}=\frac{5}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Expanding your problem:

$$ \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{k + 1}}{{3^k }}} = \frac{1}{3^0} + \frac{2}{3^1} + \frac{3}{3^2} + \frac{4}{3^3} + \dots $$

$$ = 1 + \left (\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \right) +  \left(\frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} \right) +  \left(\frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{3^3}+ \frac{1}{3^3}+ \frac{1}{3^3}\right) + \dots$$

This can be grouped into:

$$ = \left(1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \dots\right)+ $$
$$ \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \dots\right)+ $$
$$ \left(\frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \dots\right)+ $$
$$ \left(\frac{1}{3^3} + \dots\right) + \dots $$

Using the fact that $ S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n} = \frac{3}{2}$:
$$ = \frac{3}{2} + $$
$$ \frac{3}{2} - (1) + $$
$$ \frac{3}{2} - \left(1 + \frac{1}{3} \right) + $$
$$ \frac{3}{2} - \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^2} \right ) + \dots $$

The partial sum $S_k$ is computed as: $S_k = \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{1}{3^n} = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^k$

Hence,
 $$ = \frac{3}{2} + \left(\frac{3}{2} - S_0 \right) + \left(\frac{3}{2} - S_1 \right) + \left(\frac{3}{2} - S_2 \right) \dots$$
$$ = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \dots \right) $$
$$ = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2}S = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{2}$$
$$ = \mathbf{\frac{9}{4}}$$