# Strehl identity for the sum of cubes of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

In 1993 Strehl showed that
$$
\sum_k\binom nk^3=\sum_k\binom nk^2\binom{2k}n.
$$
I’m interested in a <s>combinatorial</s> proof.

**Upd (Jan '14).** Maybe the original question was too restrictive — I'm now asking for any proof.

I've written a combinatorial proof (see answers), but it's somewhat convoluted. Maybe there is a nice proof using generating functions / residues (something like [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/613436/) for the Dixon's identity), for example?..

---

*Comments and thoughts*

1. There is of course an algebraic proof (any such identity can be proved using WZ-magic of hypergeometric functions AFAIK). Feel free to post any proof, but I’m mainly interested in a combinatorial proof.
2. It’s well known that $\sum_k\binom nk=2^n$ and $\sum_k\binom nk^2=\binom{2n}n$.
   Perhaps, one should think about Stehl identity as the next member of this family.
   (Is there any analogue for degree 4, I wonder, btw?)
3. Quadratic case suggests that it’s, perhaps, better to write LHS as $\binom nk^2\binom n{n-k}$. And maybe instead of one $n$ one should introduce two or three parameters (s.t. Strehl identity corresponds to n=m[=l]). A naive approach is $\sum\binom nk\binom mk\binom m{m-k}$ but looks like $\sum\binom nk\binom mk\binom n{m-k}$ might be a better choice — actually, it's equal to $\sum\binom nk\binom mk\binom{2k}m$.
4. [arXiv:0712.3946](http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.3946) might be of some relevance. There LHS is interpreted as the number of ways to deal a deck of 3n cards (n denominations, 3 colors) to 3 players so that no player receives a card of her own color.
5. Let's write the identity in the form
   $$
   \sum_{i+j=n}\binom Bi\binom Wj\binom ni=\sum_k\binom Bk\binom Wk\binom{2k}n,
   $$
   where $B$ and $W$ are two $n$-element sets. What I want to say is that both sides count ways to choose an $n$-element subset of $B\sqcup W$ with some kind of... extension (cf. [two formulas for a trinomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/534202/), perhaps).

Comment: Oh, and if someone wants to try to google, LHS is called [Franel numbers](http://oeis.org/A000172)

Comment: Cf [Dixon's identity](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/497470/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we seek to show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^3
= \sum_{k=\lceil n/2 \rceil}^n {n\choose k}^2 {2k\choose n}.$$

With

$${n\choose k} {2k\choose n}
= \frac{(2k)!}{k!\times (n-k)! \times (2k-n)!}
= {2k\choose k} {k\choose n-k}$$

we find that the RHS is
$$\sum_{k=\lceil n/2 \rceil}^n {n\choose k}
{2k\choose k}  {k\choose n-k}.$$

Introduce
$${2k\choose k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{2k}}{z^{k+1}} \; dz$$

and (this integral is zero when $0\le k\lt \lceil n/2\rceil$)
$${k\choose n-k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{(1+w)^{k}}{w^{n-k+1}} \; dw$$

to get for the RHS

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac{w^k(1+w)^k (1+z)^{2k}}{z^k}
\; dw\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
\left(1+\frac{w(1+w)(1+z)^2}{z}\right)^n
\; dw\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
(z+w(1+w)(1+z)^2)^n
\; dw\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
(z+w(z+1))^n (1+w(z+1))^n
\; dw\; dz.$$

Extracting first the residue in $w$ in next the residue in $z$ we get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^n 
{n\choose q} z^{n-q} (1+z)^q  
{n\choose n-q} (1+z)^{n-q} \; dz
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}^2
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{q+1}} \; dz
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}^3$$

QED.

**Addendum May 27 2018.** We compute this using formal power series as
per request in comment.  Start from

$${2k\choose k} = [z^k] (1+z)^{2k}$$

and

$${k\choose n-k} = [w^{n-k}] (1+w)^k.$$

Observe that  this coefficient  extractor is zero  when $n-k\gt  k$ or
$k\lt\lceil  n/2\rceil$ where  $k\ge  0.$ Hence  we  are justified  in
lowering $k$ to zero when we substitute these into the sum and we find

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} [z^k] (1+z)^{2k} [w^{n-k}] (1+w)^k
\\ = [z^0] [w^n]  \sum_{k=0}^n 
{n\choose k} \frac{1}{z^k} (1+z)^{2k} w^k (1+w)^k
\\ = [z^0] [w^n]  
\left(1+\frac{(1+z)^2 w (1+w)}{z}\right)^n
\\ = [z^n] [w^n] (z + (1+z)^2 w (1+w))^n
\\ = [z^n] [w^n] (1+w(1+z))^n (z+w(1+z))^n.$$

We extract the coefficient on $[w^n]$ then the one on $[z^n]$ and get

$$[z^n] \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} 
(1+z)^q {n\choose n-q} (1+z)^{n-q} z^q
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}^2
[z^{n-q}] (1+z)^n
= \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}^2 {n\choose n-q}
= \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}^3.$$

The claim is proved.

Comment: Nice. Since you don't really use change of variables etc one can get rid of all integrals and get a slightly shorter version in the language of gen. functions.

Comment: The same argument proves the generalisation $\sum_k \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{k} \binom{n}{m-k} = \sum_k \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{k} \binom{2k}{m}$ of comment/thought 3 of the question.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose we have $n$ black cards and $n$ white cards and we want to divide cards into «good» and «bad» — in such way that there is the same number of bad cards of each color — and burn $n$ of bad cards.

**(RHS)** Obviously there are exactly $\sum\binom nk^2\binom{2k}n$ ways to do it: we choose $k$ bad black cards, $k$ bad white cards and burn $n$ bad cards.

**(LHS)** If we just want to choose what $n$ cards we burn — it can be done in $\sum_k\binom nk\binom n{n-k}$ ways: we choose $k$ black cards to burn and $n-k$ white cards to burn.

Let’s call bad white cards and good black cards «perverse». After we’ve burned that $n$ cards we need to choose exactly $k$ perverse cards (from the cards left): if we have $l$ good black cards, we've had $n-l$ bad white cards of which $(n-l)-(n-k)=k-l$ left.

So $$\sum\binom nk^2\binom{2k}n=\sum\binom nk\binom n{n-k}\binom nk.$$

---

// This is of course just a rewrite of an algebraic proof (based on Vandermonde convolution and aforementioned two presentations of the same trinomial coefficient) — namely, of the proof on p. 16 of V. Strehl’s «Binomial Identities...» (I’ve tried to look into the paper before — but missed it).

Comment: If you are still following this question you might want to look at my proof.

Comment: "we need to choose exactly k perverse cards (from the cards left)": Why exactly $k$?

Comment: @darijgrinberg that's explained after the colon

Comment: @GrigoryM: Oops! I've failed to realize that the $k$ was being used for something else in the analysis of the RHS than in the LHS.