# An alternating sum

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients

I ran into an alternating sum in my research and would like to know if the following identity is true:
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{\left\lfloor \left(n + 1\right)/2\right\rfloor} \frac{\left(n + 1 - 2i\right)^{n + 1}}{2^{n}\left(n + 1\right)!}\binom{n + 1}{i}\left(-1\right)^{i} = 1\quad
\forall\ \mbox{positive integers}\ n\geq 3
$$
Any help would be appreciated!.

**Edit.**
We might try to use an Iverson bracket $[[2q\le n]]$ in attempting to
evaluate

$$S_n = \sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
(n-2q)^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q.$$

We obtain

$$[v^n] \frac{1}{1-v}
\sum_{q\ge 0} v^{2q} (n-2q)^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q$$

Using a coefficient extractor,

$$n! [z^n] \exp(nz) \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-v}
\sum_{q\ge 0} v^{2q} \exp(-2qz) {n\choose q} (-1)^q
\\ = n! [z^n] \exp(nz) \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-v} (1-v^2\exp(-2z))^n.$$

Now residues sum to zero and the residue at one yields

$$- n! [z^n] \exp(nz) (1-\exp(-2z))^n.$$

We have that since $(1-\exp(-2z))^n = (2z-2z^2\pm\cdots)^n = 2^n z^n +\cdots$ this evaluates to $-2^n n!.$ We find for the residue at infinity

$$- n! [z^n] \exp(nz) \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^2}
v^{n+1} \frac{1}{1-1/v} (1-\exp(-2z)/v^2)^n
\\ = n! [z^n] \exp(nz) \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^n} \frac{1}{1-v} (v^2-\exp(-2z))^n
\\ = n! [z^n] \exp(nz) \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^n} \frac{1}{1-v}
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^{n-q} \exp(-2(n-q)z) v^{2q}
\\ = \;\underset{v}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{v^n} \frac{1}{1-v}
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^{n-q} (2q-n)^n v^{2q}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q (n-2q)^n [[2q\le n-1]].$$

Now when $n$ is odd this gives the upper limit $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ and
when $n$ is even $\lfloor n/2\rfloor -1$ however in the latter case we
may raise to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ because the added term is zero in the
sum per $(n-2q)^n = 0$. We have obtained

$$\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n\choose q} (-1)^q (n-2q)^n
= S_n.$$

Collecting everything we have shown that $S_n - 2^n n! + S_n = 0$ or
$S_n = 2^{n-1} n!.$ The question now becomes, **is there a simpler proof?**

Comment: In which mathematical problem/theory such an ugly summation occured?

Comment: I can confirm, it is true for $n=3$. So you can start with an induction.

Comment: You could also show that 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} \frac{(n+1-2i)^{n+1}}{2^n(n+1)!}\binom{n+1}{i}(-1)^i=2$$
or 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{u} \frac{(u-2i)^{u}}{u!}\binom{u}{i}(-1)^i=2^u$$

Comment: @DietrichBurde I thought about induction, but it seems that the -2i part is a bit annoying.

Comment: @BobDobbs It's a bit hard to include all the background here. I was doing some calculation with toric varieties, and this arises from a volume calculation, where I was doing the naive inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591350/expressing-a-factorial-as-difference-of-powers-sum-r-0n-binomnr-1

Comment: "the $-2i$ part is a bit annoying" $j:=(n+1)/2-i$ is the way around that, at least for odd $n$. There's already a great answer, but it's often useful to reverse the order of terms with a new choice of dummy index.

Comment: Creation/proof/disproof of. Result is Always interning thing irrespective of the fact wether it's has dome application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proof of formula and calculation sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131826/proof-of-formula-and-calculation-sum)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We seek to show that

$$\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
(n-2q)^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q
= 2^{n-1} n!.$$

Observe that

$$(n-2q)^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q
= \frac{1}{2}
\left[ (n-2q)^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q
+ (2q-n)^n {n\choose n-q} (-1)^{n-q} \right].$$

Hence we get for our sum

$$\frac{1}{2}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
(n-2q)^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q
+ \frac{1}{2}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
(2q-n)^n {n\choose n-q} (-1)^{n-q}
\\ = \frac{1}{2}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
(n-2q)^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q
+ \frac{1}{2}
\sum_{q=n-\lfloor n/2\rfloor}^n
(n-2q)^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q
\\ = \frac{1}{2}
\sum_{q=0}^n
(n-2q)^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q.$$

Introducing a coefficient extractor,

$$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q
n! [z^n] \exp((n-2q) z)
\\ = \frac{1}{2} n! [z^n] \exp(nz)
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (-1)^q
\exp((-2q) z)
\\ = \frac{1}{2} n! [z^n] \exp(nz)
(1-\exp(-2z))^n.$$

Note however that $(1-\exp(-2z))^n = (2z-2z^2\pm\cdots)^n$ so the only
contribution to the coefficient extractor $[z^n]$ is from the first
term of the series so that $[z^n] \exp(nz) (2z-2z^2\pm\cdots)^n = 2^n$ and we
finally have

$$2^{n-1} n!$$

as claimed.