# Calculating a recursive power term binomial sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, summation

Could someone please help me or give me a hint on how to calculate this sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}(x-2(k+1))^n.$$

I have been trying for a few hours now and I start thinking it may be not possible to find the answer directly, I also think it is equal to:
$$x^n+(-2)^{n}n!.$$
The right answer is in fact:
$$(-2)^{n}n!.$$

Thank you very much,

Comment: As you think you have found a closed form, you could try to show it by induction.

Comment: Are you sure it's equal? A quick calculation with anything like $n=2$ and $x=2$ for example produces different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The summand $(x-2(k+1))^n$ is $(-2k)^n$ plus a polynomial in $k$ of degree less than $n$. Now use the formulas [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-prove-that-sum-limits-i-0p-1p-i-p-choose-i-ij-is-0-for) to show that your expression is $(-2)^n n!$, (without $x$).

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try like that when I have a moment!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} 
(-1)^{n-k} (x-2(k+1))^n.$$

Introduce
$$(x-2(k+1))^n = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \exp((x-2(k+1))z) \; dz.$$

This yields for the sum
$$\frac{n!\times (-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k \exp((x-2(k+1))z) \; dz
\\ = \frac{n!\times (-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \exp((x-2)z)
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k \exp(-2kz) \; dz
\\ = \frac{n!\times (-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \exp((x-2)z)
(1-\exp(-2z))^n \; dz.$$

Now the series for $1-\exp(-2z)$  starts at $2z$ and hence the residue
times the factor is
$$n!\times (-1)^n\times 2^n.$$