# expanded geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having some issues with the following series
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} n^p r^n
$$
for a fixed positive integer $p$ and some real $r > 0$.

Is there any way to avoid going through linear combinations of the derivatives of the usual geometric series:
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(n+p)!}{n!}r^n = \frac{d^p}{dr^p}\left( \frac{1}{1-r}\right)
$$

Also, is there a name for such things? It isn't a Dirichlet series right?

Comment: See the answers to the question [$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty }n^{2}/x^{n}$ to $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty }n^{p}/x^{n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/4317/752).