# Solution to infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, infinity

I am looking for a step-by-step solution to the following infinite sum:

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{i^n}{4^i}$

I know that I can find the solution to something like this:

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{i^2}{4^i}$

by starting with the geometric series and its closed form:

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i = \frac{1}{(1-x)}$

and by differentiating both sides by x then multiplying both sides by x and repeating (perform differentiation by x followed by multiplication by x) i can get:

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty i^2x^i = \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$

at which point I just set x = (1/4) and the RHS evaluates to 20/27.

But I am unsure of what to do when the power of i in the series is set to n, instead of a constant like 2 or 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generalizing $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty }n^{2}/x^{n}$ to $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty }n^{p}/x^{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/generalizing-sum-limits-n-1-infty-n2-xn-to-sum-limits-n-1)

Answer (score 0):

Let
$s(x, n)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^n x^k
$.

$s(x, 0)
=\dfrac1{1-x}
$.

$s'(x, n)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{n+1} x^{k-1}
=\dfrac1{x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{n+1} x^{k}
=\dfrac1{x}s(x, n+1)
$.

Therefore
$s(x, n+1)
=xs'(x, n)
$.

$s(x, 1)
=xs'(x, 0)
=x(\dfrac1{1-x})'
=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$.

$s(x, 2)
=xs'(x, 1)
=x(\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2})'
=\dfrac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}
$.

$s(x, 3)
=xs'(x, 2)
=x(\dfrac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3})'
=\dfrac{x(1+4x+x^2)}{(1-x)^4}
$.

$s(x, 4)
=xs'(x, 3)
=x(\dfrac{x(1+4x+x^2)}{(1-x)^4})'
=\dfrac{x (x^3 + 11 x^2 + 11 x + 1)}{(1-x)^5}
$.

$s(\frac14, 4)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^4 (\frac14)^k
=\dfrac{\frac14 ((\frac14)^3 + 11 (\frac14)^2 + 11 (\frac14) + 1)}{(1-\frac14)^5}
=\dfrac{380}{81}
$.